# What's an alternative way to wright a nested for loop instead of single line for loop below? I have been getting index errors on my current solution

Tags: python, numpy

[image: example question]

```
import sys
import numpy as np

myarray=[]
for j in range(3):
    myarray.append(j)
    for i in range (3):
            myarray[i]=i+j
print(myarray)
```

Comment: ... you could also do that with `np.tile(np.arange(3), (3, 1)) + np.arange(3)[None].T`

Answer (score -1):

The key thing to understand is you are creating nested lists here. You need to create an intermediate list on each outer iteration to append to the final list.

```
>>> result = []
>>> for j in range(3):
...     intermediate = []
...     for i in range(3):
...         intermediate.append(i+j)
...     result.append(intermediate)
...
>>> result
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, however the output returned was only [2,3,4], is there any way to tweak it to receive [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

Comment: @racheltan no it didn't, I'm showing you the exact output from the interpreter. Check your code or post a [mcve]